# Flash plugin doesn't appear in Opera

Tags: flash, opera

I use Opera, I have the latest version, and I just installed flash, it says to go to the Plugins menu and click 'Enable', however there is no Flash plugin on the PLugins menu. I found some answers relating to Windows saying to use a command line switch, such as here: http://forums.opera.com/discussion/comment/15193364#Comment_15193364, but I don't how to do this in Ubuntu.

I'm on the latest Ubuntu, 64-bit. Not sure what other details are needed.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Try this https://askubuntu.com/q/986162/203581

Answer (score 3):

**Opera & Pepper flash**

Opera Forums: http://forums.opera.com/discussion/1850996/pepper-flash-on-linux/p1

> ruario    December 2014
>
> If you use Ubuntu or Debian install the pepperflashplugin-nonfree
>   package.

Ubuntu package: http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=pepperflashplugin-nonfree&searchon=names&suite=all&section=all

More can be found:

- https://wiki.debian.org/PepperFlashPlayer
- https://wiki.debian.org/PepperFlashPlayer/Installing

Comment: It just download google chrome and uses that browser's plugin. Just installing chrome also works

Answer (score 1):

In Opera v 37 flash was not working until I installed the following two packages:
adobe-flashplugin
1:20160512.1-0ubuntu0.14.04.1
AND
adobe-flash-properties-kde
1:20160512.1-0ubuntu0.14.04.1

OS: Kubuntu 14.04 with Opera-stable v 37.0.2178.43

Nothing else worked. No pepper, no official adobe flash from the adobe website copying to all possible places nor creating new folders in /usr/lib/opera/plugins nor .... but finally with these two files it works.

Answer (score 1):

First you should check if flash player is properly installed:

```
sudo update-pepperflashplugin-nonfree --status
```

In new Opera the most appropriate way to flash player work is using **PPAPI** flash player interface supported by default in **multiverse** repository in Ubuntu, not adobe-flashplugin, full description how to do that [is here](http://ubuntu.pl/forum/viewtopic.php?f=152&t=180008).