# Brightness on asus X550JX

Tags: laptop, brightness, asus

I'm really new in this thing with ubuntu. I have this laptop X550JX(asus) and I don't know how can I set the brightness from keys. If anyone can help me it will be awesome. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Indicator Brightness applet. You can get it on [Launchpad](https://launchpad.net/~indicator-brightness/+archive/ubuntu/ppa/+packages) or install it from the ppa using the following commands in the terminal:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:indicator-brightness/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install indicator-brightness
```

After you install it, reboot your device. Then you can set the shortcuts to control brightness. Go to System settings -> Keyboard -> Shortcuts -> Custom Shortcuts. Add two shortcuts for the the following commands

```
/opt/extras.ubuntu.com/indicator-brightness/indicator-brightness-adjust --up
/opt/extras.ubuntu.com/indicator-brightness/indicator-brightness-adjust --down
```

Then you can assign your custom shortcut to them by clicking on the Disabled and pressing required keys.

Comment: Have you tried rebooting your device after the installation?

Comment: I did the steps again and rebooted and it's working now. Thank you a lot. It's pretty strange why isn't working with the "fn" key, because I can control the volume with FN+f11/f12 like in windows. Thank you again and have a nice day!

Comment: don't you know how can I fix the flash problem in opera? I tried almost everything I found on internet. The facebook videos are not working in opera but they do in firefox.

Comment: I have found [an answer](http://askubuntu.com/questions/630835/flash-plugin-doesnt-appear-in-opera) that might solve your flash problem. If it doesn't, please ask a new question. Also if my previous answer helped you, you can mark it as accepted.